# Oracle SQL, my WHERE clause restricting specific year

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I want to display all customers who placed an order during 2010. When I display "customerid" and "orderdate" from the custorder table, the format looks like this:

```
C-300064    06-DEC-10
```

Basically I need to figure out how to get it to display only customerid where the last 2 digits of orderdate are 10.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Add some sample table data along with the expected result! Formatted text please, not images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wanting to display all customers who placed an order during 2010.

As simple as:

```
SELECT  customerid , orderdate
FROM your_table
WHERE orderdate >= DATE '2010-01-01' AND orderdate < DATE '2011-01-01';
```

If orderdate is `DATE` column then how it is displayed doesn't matter. `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` literal does not depend on your session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: I did see that layout a few different places, but wasn't sure if that's what I was supposed to do since the date format in this database (06-DEC-10) is different than what you have written (2010-12-10). Or am I mistaken, or does it not matter?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Ty for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: the date format you see is a function of the NLS settings on the User interface tool you have.  Date datatypes are stored in the system w/o this formatting.  It's just presented to us this way based on the NLS settings. the SQL standard is YYYYMMDD for inserting dates if you really wanted to be precise and avoid implicit casting use `to_date('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')` so the system casts the string to a date where you specify the format so no ambiguity can exist. though date literal works as well; just appends on preference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Oracle, this will work.

```
SELECT 
      customerid
    , orderdate
FROM yourtable 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orderdate) = 2010;
```

Comment: and there goes the index use.  it works; it just that it's slower.

Comment: Great, and please mention that it will skip the index if exist on that column, or you have to create function index.

Comment: Fair enough... I stand corrected. However, there was no information regarding the size of the table. Unless he has millions of customers, he will likely not notice much difference.

Comment: With millions of records in 2010 use of index would be inefficient any way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you have several ways to achieve this using a WHERE clause on the "orderdate" column. However, when using Oracle SQL, you may need some additional code to account for different date formats. I believe these examples should work for you:

```sql
SELECT t1.customerid, t1.orderdate
FROM some_table t1
WHERE t1.orderdate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31';

SELECT t1.customerid, t1.orderdate
FROM some_table t1
WEHRE t1.orderdate > '2016-12-31' AND  t1.orderdate < '2018-01-01';

SELECT t1.customerid, t1.orderdate
FROM some_table t1
WHERE NOT ('2017-01-01' > t1.orderdate OR '2017-12-31' < t1.orderdate);
```

The BETWEEN method takes a little longer to process, so I would recommend the bottom two options (WHERE and WHERE NOT).

I've built a fiddle that shows these three examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38063/1

Good luck!